# Creating vertical bar in xml

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, vector

I am trying to create a signal bar of the vertical line but I am unable to give the radius as given in the below pictures.

My current implementation

```
  <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="26.086dp"
    android:height="22.319dp"
    android:viewportWidth="26.086"
    android:viewportHeight="22.319">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0,22.319h5.332v-4.562Z"
        android:fillColor="#BC1B61"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M6.918,16.4L6.918,22.323h5.332L12.25,11.838Z"
        android:fillColor="#eee"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M13.836,10.476v11.838h5.332v-16.4Z"
        android:fillColor="#eee"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M20.754,4.562L20.754,22.319h5.332L26.086,0Z"
        android:fillColor="#eee" />
</vector>
```

[image: singal]